# Is there a way to make tabbed pdf display working in Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, microsoft-edge

This html to display 3 pdf according to the button clicked works in Firefox and Chrome. It does not display the pdf's in Edge after the first time the second or third button is clicked. But it does display the pdf's when a button is clicked for the second time.
What would cause this? And if it is a bug in Edge, is there a workaround?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .row-container {
            flex: 1 1 100vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .first-row {
            background-color: beige;
        }

        .second-row {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            flex-direction: column;
            display: flex;
            border: 3px solid lightblue;
            min-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .frame {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            border: 0;
        }

        .active {
          display: block;
        }
        .hidden {
          display: none;
        }

        .selected {
          color: white;
          background-color: blue;
        }
        .not-selected {
          color: black;
          background-color: lightblue;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row-container">
        <div class="first-row">
            <p>just some text here</p>
            <nav>
                <div id="nav-tab">
                    <button id="but1" class="button selected">Dummy</button>
                    <button id="but2" class="button not-selected">Lorem</button>
                    <button id="but3" class="button not-selected">Resume</button>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="second-row" id="nav-tabContent">
            <iframe class="frame active" id="pdf-but1"
              src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf">
            </iframe>

            <iframe class="frame hidden" id="pdf-but2"
              src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf">
            </iframe>

            <iframe class="frame hidden" id="pdf-but3"
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Resume.pdf">
            </iframe>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
      var frames = document.getElementsByClassName("frame");
      var i

      function click() {
        for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
          if (buttons[i].id != this.id) {
            buttons[i].setAttribute("class", "button not-selected");
            frames[i].setAttribute("class", "frame hidden");
          }
        }
        this.setAttribute("class", "button selected");
        document.getElementById("pdf-" + this.id).setAttribute("class", "frame active");
      }

      for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", click)
      }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to test the issue with the **Microsoft Edge (Chromium)** browser Version **88.0.705.74** and found that when we click the second or third button for the first time then it is taking time and the PDF file does not get appear.

I noticed that you are setting the `display: none` to the `Iframe` to hide it.

I think the Edge browser is not rendering the PDF for those hidden Iframes and when you set the `display: block`, it is causing this issue.

You can notice that if we scroll a little bit then PDF will get appear properly.

As an alternative solution for this issue, I suggest you can overlap the Iframes on each other and use the `zIndex` to bring the Iframe on the top using the button click.

Example:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>demo</title>
      <style>
         body {
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
         align-items: center;
         overflow: hidden;
         }
         .row-container {
         flex: 1 1 100vh;
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
         overflow: hidden;
         width: 100%;
         background-color: red;
         }
         .first-row {
         background-color: beige;
         }
         .second-row {
         flex: 1 1 auto;
         flex-direction: column;
         display: flex;
         border: 3px solid lightblue;
         min-height: 0;
         overflow: hidden;
         }
         .selected {
         color: white;
         background-color: blue;
         }
         .not-selected {
         color: black;
         background-color: lightblue;
         }
         .frame {
         flex: 1 1 auto;
         border: 0;
         display:block;
         width:100%;
         height:92%;
         }
         .frm1{
         position:absolute;
         background-color: red;
         z-index: 2;
         }
         .frm2{
         position:absolute;
         background-color: green;
         z-index: 1;
         }
         .frm3{
         position:absolute;
         background-color: yellow;
         z-index: 0;
         }
      </style>
      <script>
         function fun1() {
           document.getElementById('pdf-but1').style.zIndex = 2;
           document.getElementById('pdf-but2').style.zIndex = 0;
           document.getElementById('pdf-but3').style.zIndex = 1;
           document.getElementById('btn1').setAttribute("class", "button selected");
           document.getElementById('btn2').setAttribute("class", "button not-selected");
           document.getElementById('btn3').setAttribute("class", "button not-selected");
         }
         
         function fun2() {
           document.getElementById('pdf-but1').style.zIndex = 1;
           document.getElementById('pdf-but2').style.zIndex = 2;
           document.getElementById('pdf-but3').style.zIndex = 0;
           document.getElementById('btn1').setAttribute("class", "button not-selected");
           document.getElementById('btn2').setAttribute("class", "button selected");
           document.getElementById('btn3').setAttribute("class", "button not-selected");
         }
         function fun3() {
          document.getElementById('pdf-but1').style.zIndex = 0;
           document.getElementById('pdf-but2').style.zIndex = 1;
           document.getElementById('pdf-but3').style.zIndex = 2;
           document.getElementById('btn1').setAttribute("class", "button not-selected");
           document.getElementById('btn2').setAttribute("class", "button not-selected");
           document.getElementById('btn3').setAttribute("class", "button selected");
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="row-container">
         <div class="first-row">
            <p>just some text here</p>
            <nav>
               <div id="nav-tab">
                  <button id="btn1" onclick="fun1()" class="selected">Dummy</button>
                  <button id="btn2" onclick="fun2()" class="not-selected">Lorem</button>
                  <button id="btn3" onclick="fun3()" class="not-selected">Resume</button>
               </div>
            </nav>
         </div>
         <div class="second-row" id="nav-tabContent">
            <iframe class="frm1 frame" id="pdf-but1"
               src="https://freshmindsgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/LoremIpsumH101-2016.pdf">
            </iframe>
            <iframe class="frm2 frame" id="pdf-but2"
               src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf">
            </iframe>
            <iframe class="frm3 frame" id="pdf-but3"
               src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Resume.pdf">
            </iframe>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Output in the Edge browser:**

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code example as per your own requirements.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks, it works but for one problem: on a pdf with more than one page the bottom of the last page is not displayed when you scroll down. This is the care with the pdf under the 'lorem' button. Because that pdf does not have text on the bottom of the last page you did not notice that difference.

If you replace one of the src="..." to               src="https://freshmindsgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/LoremIpsumH101-2016.pdf"
you will notice that on page 2 it has a pagenumber in the bottom wich is not displayed while in my version it is displayed (in Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: The problem with the display height of the pdf becomes more visible bij increasing the number of lines 'just some text here'. If you copy that 10 times, it is noticeable the last part of the pdf is not displayed, equal to the heightdecrease in the iframe.

Comment: You need to set the `height:92%;` in the `.frame ` class to fix the page height issue. I have updated my answer with the modified version of the code. You can check it. If you think this suggestion can help you to fix your original issue then I suggest you please mark the helpful suggestion as an answer to this thread. Thanks for your understanding.